# Crystal reports XI suppress duplicated data from summeries

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a problem removing duplicates from my report.

I have a table named "Calendar" with employees working days and hours, like this in the image below:

http://postimg.com/182000/calendar-181842.jpg.

I have designed a report where I have grouped by EmployeeID. I the Group detail section I have inserted
an Formula field to count the working days.

I have suppressed the field duplicates but the problem is in the calculations of summaries of other fields. For example: I want the sum of employees salaries, but is sums for each employees (the number of days he has worked ) 23 times the salary. In the end the total is huge.

I will give the image link below to see the result:

http://postimg.com/182000/repotpreview-181841.jpg

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Group by `EmployeeID` and place `Day` in detail then take the `count` in group footer of `EmployeeID`

Comment: I haven't used any group, my report is simple only with detail. Like in the question description..

Comment: Though you didn't use any group to achieve your requirement you need to use grouping in report.

Comment: I made the group but when I place the Day in Detail it will show all the days. I want it to show only the count of the Days.

Comment: You can get count by right click and insert summary there select count

Comment: This is my result: http://s8.postimg.org/7kaz2cl3p/report.png.
Even if I remove the Day from the detail it will be filled with NULL values. And the Footer total with sum all the 21 results.

Comment: If you don't want the count then supress the detail... then that data will be hidden